# Linked event listeners using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have this HTML structure

```
<div class="buttons">
    <button data-icon="ui-icon-disk" class="save">Save1</button>
    <button data-icon="ui-icon-check" class="ok">OK1</button>
    <button data-icon="ui-icon-trash" class="delete">Delete1</button>
    <button data-icon="ui-icon-close" class="close">Close1</button>
</div>
```

There are many blocks in the page like this one.
Some buttons come with click handlers functions (save and delete buttons).

What I want to do is: if someone click on an **ok** button, the **corresponding**  **save** button click bound function should run.

My code:

```
$('.save').click(function(){
    alert('save');
});
$('.ok').click(function(){
    $('.save').click();
});
```

This is wrong, when I click on a **ok** button **all** save buttons fires... not only the one within the same buttons group.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nMnm7/) illustrating my problem.

Comment: jQuery's documentation is helpful too: http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use [siblings](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/)

```
$('.ok').click(function(){
    $(this).siblings('.save').click();
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nMnm7/1/)

Answer (score 5):

Use `$(this).siblings('.save').click()` to select only siblings of the clicked button instead of all matching buttons in the whole document.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThiefMaster/nMnm7/2/
Docs:  http://api.jquery.com/siblings/

Answer (score 1):

http://api.jquery.com/siblings/

```
$('.ok').click(function(){
   $(this).siblings(".save").click();
});
```